# Como enviar una notificación desde la app

Tags: android, android-notifications

Estoy creando una aplicación y quiero que avise a través de una notificación cuando se realicen x comportamientos en la aplicación. Genere una función para que me cree la notificación y funciona bien, pero solo funciona si la ejecuto a través de un botón por ejemplo.

¿Hay forma de invocar dicha función constantemente mientra la aplicación esta cerrada?

Mi función es la siguiente:

```
public void crearnotificacion (String xid){
    if(id_actual!=xid){

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =(NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int icono = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, mensajeactivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, i, 0);

        mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icono)
                .setContentTitle("Nueva id!")
                .setContentText("Esto es un mensaje de prueba")
                .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿cuando la aplicación esta cerrada como determinarías el envío?

Comment: no lo se, que alternativas tengo?

Comment: Si la aplicación esta en verdad cerrada en realidad tienes que implementar FCM

Answer (score 0):

Creando un [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) puedes iniciarle así la aplicación esté en Background o completamente inactiva.

Algo como esto en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>
    ...
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </receiver>
```

La acción `BOOT_COMPLETED` es para que inicie desde el momento en que el teléfono se enciende.

Y en la clase `MyReceiver.java`

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /* Inicia aqui lo que quieras hacer,
           como llamar a crearNotificacion() */
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva, ¡éxitos!

Comment: En background se puede pero el OP indica "mientras la aplicación esta cerrada".

Comment: Igual funciona si la aplicación está cerrada, mientras se le asigne como Intent el BOOT_COMPLETED para que accione onReceive desde el momento en que el teléfono se enciende, independiente de si la aplicación está abierta o cerrada.

Comment: y como podría enviarle la notificación?

Comment: no me funciono, no se que estaré haciendo mal